# How can I use node-sendmail to send emails? This package crashed the server

Tags: node.js, express, sendmail, nodemailer, mailer

I'm using the node-Sendmail npm package in my express JS app, which is like the MVC structure. I have some weird errors, like

```
node_modules\sendmail\sendmail.js:291
    if (mail.to) {
             ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'to')
```

[image]

Please see the image above. I tried to send the email when the login route was requested, but it sent the email after the server crashed, and this error showed. I checked their official GitHub and asked a question, but no one replied. Have you ever used a node-Sendmail package?

I checked to see if there were any errors in the node module package and code, and here is a screenshot.

[image]

I called the Sendmail with import module :

[image]

Comment: Please enter code into your question in the form of a code snippet and not as images. This allows people to find your question more easily using the search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `sendmail` with no configuration on line 47, that is throwing your error

Comment: I update the question can you please see that again

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.